# Network operation no longer completes when placed in an operation queue

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

I have some code I want to add to an operation queue, the problem is the code functions when its not in the queue, but once added to the queue nothing happens.

Here's the code I want to add to the queue:

```
NSString* graphRequest = @"https://graph.facebook.com/redacted/picture?type=square";
FBRequest *fbRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath: graphRequest];
[fbRequest startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *theError)
 {
     NSLog(@"Completed");
 }];
```

When the code above is executed then its completion block is invoked in a couple of seconds or so.

However if I try to execute the same code in an operation queue then the completion block is never invoked:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperationWithBlock:
 ^{
    NSString* graphRequest = @"https://graph.facebook.com/redacted/picture?type=square";
    FBRequest *fbRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath: graphRequest];
    [fbRequest startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *theError)
     {
         NSLog(@"Completed");
     }];
}];
```

With this code nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `FBRequest` will only work on the main thread for some reason. You really should not worry too much about it, since `startWithCompletionHandler` runs async anyway. If you really want to use `NSOperationQueue` you will have to to a `dispatch_async` to the main thread.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, there's a bunch of other code (including more async network activity) to go into the block so I wanted to bundle everything up into a queue block.

Comment: @Mungbeans You're welcome, in that case you can do that, just dispatch that code to the main thread and let it execute everything else on the separate thread.